# IP address of docker-machine created with the hyperv driver

Tags: docker-compose, hyper-v

I create a docker machine names `dockerhyperv` using the command `docker-machine create -d hyperv dockerhyperv`
I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, call `docker-compose up` and the logs look good but I cannot connect to on the port from the yml file.
I eventually found out about the command `docker-machine ip` and noticed the docker has a different IP address than my host.

I have no idea why this is the case. Does it have to do with hyper-v settings? I expect(ed) docker to run on localhost.
In the past I played with the virtualbox driver but this should not interfere with hyper-v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Docker Machine` creates a VM since any OS other than Linux can't natively run containers.

In case of VirtualBox, I believe it creates port forward rules to allow things to work on `localhost` but is probably not the case with `Hyper-V`.

You could probably just the VM settings to use your external network to get an IP from your router. Check this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#2-set-up-a-new-external-network-switch-optional) for information on setting this up.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#run-containers-and-experiment-with-machine-commands) advise to look at the IP, I oversaw that. Thanks for your answer.